# c++ searching and sorting in student list

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search

What I want to do is to make a searching engine for searching student`s grade in student list with student number and student name. If multiple students match the requested name, the system will ask the user to enter the student id.

I have done the read txt file, however, I stopped at changing txt to array for storing and searching. I don't know how to store those data into array.

I got 20 students and here's two examples of student's grading in each subject:

> SS6709 Peter   VT001   C   VT002   E   VT003   D   VT004   D   VT009   A+  VY018   A++ VT024   B
>
> SS9830 Amy VT001   D   VT002   C   VT003   C   VT004   D   VT009   D   VT018   D   VT023   B

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: After you get the basics done, you might want to look into some of the nice [algorithms in the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: put your data in a multi_map, where you use student name as key. if you have multiple students with same name, iterate over find results in order to find id.

Comment: Also, you do know about structures and classes? Maybe you want to read something from the beginners section of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: @Jepessen: The first field seems to be an unique identifier; a map should suffice.

Comment: You'll have to store the data one character at a time.
->open file
->while end of file
  ->read character
  -> store in an array
->close file

Comment: @dario_ramos I agree but he wants to search using student name at first, so I think that using name as key will be faster in most cases, and only when are same, serch by ID. if he wants to search by ID in first place, I'd suggest the same thing as you.

Comment: @Jepessen You can always have multiple collections. One vector to store the data, then a few mappings with references to the objects in the vector, for easy searching.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're also right, there are a lot of possibilities. I've just said the first thing in my mind.

Comment: thankyou for all urs response, if theres a requirement that all searching and sorting can only refer to string array in my prog, after loading the txt file,i cant read and write in txt file.As a beginner, i feel lost in convert those student`s info to 3d array.......=(

Answer (score 1):

1. think and define a `class Item` that will represent a single `item` that will hold the data about a single student (code, name, ...)
2. create an empty `std::vector` of those structures that will hold your "items"
3. open the file for reading
4. read the file line-by-line (use `std::getline` to get WHOLE lines, not just `filestream.getline` or `file >> var` operator)

   1. (for each line that you read)
   2. read the line as `std::string`, just as `std::getline` wants
   3. create a `Item` for holding next group of data
   4. analyze the line and cut/copy the student's code into `myItem.code`
   5. analyze the line and cut/copy the student's name into `myItem.name`
   6. analyze the line and cut/copy the XXXXXXXXXXXXXX into `myItem.whateverelse`
   7. append the `myItem` that you have just read to the `vector` that you prepared earlier
5. close the file after reading all lines

Now you have a 'vector' that holds all the data, nicely stored as "items" that each have a code, name, and other data. You can now loop/search over that vector to find if any name or code matches.

Comment: u give me a great procedure, thx a lot =) i will try my best !

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to create your own data structure to store the values. You can define your own struct

```
struct Student{
 string name
 string iD
 ....
};
```

and use a array of type  in this case Student

```
Student data_base[100];
```

this is a very basic approach but it should get you going...